# Bootstrap menu click event in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

**HTML :**

```
<ul id="Mydatatabs" class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#details" id="TabDetailsLink">Personal
      Details</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1" id="Tabtab1Link">tab1</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab2" id="Tabtab2Link">tab2</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab3" id="Tabtab3Link">tab3</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab4" id="Tabtab4Link">tab4</a></li>
</ul>
```

**JS :**

```
$("#Mydatatabs li").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    alert(1);
    var MyID = $("#MyID").val();

    alert(2);
    switch ($(this).children(":first").attr("href")) {
    alert(3);
        case "#tab1":
});
```

Here I am unable to recieve the click event . Looks like I am making some mistake. Can someone show me the right way.

Comment: i think you have declared your js before the elements has been loaded

Comment: It is after the form

Comment: <html><form>here is my tab</form>here my script refernce</html> . My js reference is in the layout. if i look at the sorce i will get the above structure

Comment: ow try to see the console.. you must be receiving an error on your code.. the closing brackets are not equal

Comment: try binding the click to the document instead eg ($(document).on("click", "#Mydatatabs li", function (e) { ...) see if that helps -- https://jsfiddle.net/5d0rxg88/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the JS is loaded first the DOM is not ready yet so it could not find the `Mydatatabs` list, you should put your code inside ready function :

```
$(function(){
    //Your code here
})
```

Hope this helps.

---

```js
$(function(){

  $("#Mydatatabs li").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert(1);
    var MyID = $("#MyID").val();
    alert(2);
  });

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<ul id="Mydatatabs" class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
  <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#details" id="TabDetailsLink">Personal
    Details</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1" id="Tabtab1Link">tab1</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab2" id="Tabtab2Link">tab2</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab3" id="Tabtab3Link">tab3</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab4" id="Tabtab4Link">tab4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Yes, it worked. It resolves my issue.Thank you for your time .

Answer (score 0):

So, first you have to put your jquery code inside a document ready statement. See the example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //... code
});
```

This is to be certain that the element to which the .click() event is bound has been created when the function executes.

For further explanation, look this response: [Why should $.click() be enclosed within $(document).ready()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10092762/why-should-click-be-enclosed-within-document-ready)

And is not missing any end curly braces in this click event? In between switch case and end of the function?

Comment: i have not copied the complete code . I wanted to show how i was triggering the click event.

Comment: Ok, I see! Thanks, Jubi.