# HTML hover button list click event child

Tags: javascript, html

I need to get the click event while the list clicked

Here is html code,

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div id="myList" class="dropdown-content"> 
  </div>
</div>
```

For click event

```
  <script>
     $('#myList').click(function(event){
      event.stopPropagation();
      alert(event.target.id);
     });

  </script>
```

And the list is filling from JSON data

```
  for(var i = 0; i < jsonStr.length; i++) {
        var obj = jsonStr[i];
        //console.log(obj);
        var node = document.createElement("a");
        var textnode = document.createTextNode(obj);
        node.appendChild(textnode);
        document.getElementById("myList").appendChild(node);   
   }
```

**JSON data**

`["live0.ts","2.mpg"]`

But when clicked the list the event is not triggering.

Comment: provide the json data ?

Comment: but you are not assigning any id to the a tag. Then how the `event.target.id` will return value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this...
 your click event should be enclosed in the `$(document).ready` function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#myList').click(function(event){
      event.stopPropagation();
      alert(event.target.id);
     });
});
```

explanation here: [Why should $.click() be enclosed within $(document).ready()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10092762/why-should-click-be-enclosed-within-document-ready)