# Dynamically Change the Number of Textboxes on a Web Page

Tags: jquery, html, textbox

I'm trying to create a search bar which dynamically changes the number of search fields depending on which option (radio button) is selected. The code works in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ultraj/cu0m860q/. I'm not sure why the code below doesn't work saved locally, unless I'm missing a required library?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>  
  
  <script>

   $('#radio_Search_BB').click(function()
   {  
    $('#searchall_field1').width(100);
    $('#searchall_field2').width(300);
    $('#searchall_field2').show();
      
    $('#searchall_field1').attr('placeholder','Account');
    $('#searchall_field2').attr('placeholder','Company');
   });

   $('#radio_Search_RC').click(function()
   {
    $('#searchall_field1').width(400);
    $('#searchall_field1').attr('placeholder','Keywords');

    $('#searchall_field2').hide();  
   });
  
  </script>
 </head>

 <body>
  <p>jQuery: <script>document.write ($.fn.jquery);</script></p>
   
  <form id="" name="form_Search_All" action="search.php" method="post">
   <input id="searchall_field1" type="text" style="width: 100px;" name="searchall_field1" placeholder="Account">
   <input id="searchall_field2" type="text" style="width: 300px;" name="searchall_field2" placeholder="Company">      
      
   <input type="submit" name="btnSearch_All" value="+" />

   <span>
    <input type="radio" value="BB" name="radio_Search" id="radio_Search_BB" checked>
    <label for="radio_Search_BB">BB</label>
   </span>
   <span>
    <input type="radio" value="RC" name="radio_Search" id="radio_Search_RC">
    <label for="radio_Search_RC">RC</label>
   </span>
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you getting any error in console?

Comment: There is no way to determine why it's not working in an instance by looking at another instance where it's working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added **$(document).ready()** to make sure the **.click()** event has been created when the function executes.

Take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10092762/why-should-click-be-enclosed-within-document-ready).

```html
<html>
     <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />

      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
      
      <script>
        $( document ).ready(function() {
            $('#radio_Search_BB').click(function()
            {  
              $('#searchall_field1').width(100);
              $('#searchall_field2').width(300);
              $('#searchall_field2').show();

              $('#searchall_field1').attr('placeholder','Account');
              $('#searchall_field2').attr('placeholder','Company');
            });

            $('#radio_Search_RC').click(function()
            {
              $('#searchall_field1').width(400);
              $('#searchall_field1').attr('placeholder','Keywords');

              $('#searchall_field2').hide();  
            });
        
         });
      
      </script>
     </head>

     <body>
      <p>jQuery: <script>document.write ($.fn.jquery);</script></p>
       
      <input id="searchall_field1" type="text" style="width: 100px;" name="searchall_field1" placeholder="Account">
        <input id="searchall_field2" type="text" style="width: 300px;" name="searchall_field2" placeholder="Company">

        <span>
            <input type="radio" value="BB" name="radio_Search" id="radio_Search_BB" checked>
            <label for="radio_Search_BB">BB</label>
        </span>
        <span>
            <input type="radio" value="RC" name="radio_Search" id="radio_Search_RC">
            <label for="radio_Search_RC">RC</label>
        </span>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Could you please mention why the answer is not useful?

Comment: Hi Mils. Thanks! That works. I'm not sure why someone would -1 that.

Comment: Answers without a brief explanation on what the code does, what changed compared to the question or what was wrong in the question in the first place are not useful and considered low quality, because they tend to only help the OP, instead of helping all future visitors with a similar problem. Please read [answer] for details.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Andrei, I updated the answer.