# jQuery script for closing parent element not working unless separated in jsfiddle

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a banner on my website that viewers should be able to close via a button.

I have solved this with a script I have found here on stackoverflow (thanks!) and tailored it to my needs.

The problem is that the script only works when it's seperated in JSfiddle into the Javascript+jQuery bottom-left box. As soon as I put it in the header or body it doesnt work anymore.

It must be something simple I'm missing, like a syntax problem,  but I can't figure it out as I'm not familiar with anything else than CSS/HTML.

Could anyone help me please?

- JSFiddle not working but how I need it: https://jsfiddle.net/AlphaX/ud40gwy3/26/
- JSFiddle working in JSFiddle only: https://jsfiddle.net/AlphaX/ud40gwy3/27/

Thanks so much!!

Alpha

```css
.banner {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100px;
  opacity: 0.6;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding-top: 5px;
}

.close {
  color: #fff;
  filter: alpha(opacity=20);
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1;
  opacity: .8;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  filter: alpha(opacity=50);
  opacity: 1;
  text-decoration: none;
}

button.close {
  background: transparent;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $('.close').on("click", function() {
      $(this).parents('div').fadeOut();
    });
  </script>

  <div class="banner well notice bg-green">


    Close this banner <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should wrap your js code by anonymous jquery function to be loaded after page contend load no matter where you place the code, like below:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('.close').on("click", function() {
        $(this).parents('div').fadeOut();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Oh, yes, it is because of use `.parents('div')` which selects all parents divs, try to change this part to `.parent('div')` or `.closest('div')`

Comment: thanks this really helped to just close the exact div (button) and not any other! Thanks so much!!!

Answer (score 2):

EDIT stop whole page close try this:

```
$('.close').on("click", function() {
        $(this).parent('div').fadeOut();
      });
```

Edit you could also change your script to run once the document is ready that way it can find the div to hide:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.close').on("click", function() {
        $(this).parents('div').fadeOut();
      });
    });
```

```css
.banner {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100px;
  opacity: 0.6;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding-top: 5px;
}

.close {
  color: #fff;
  filter: alpha(opacity=20);
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1;
  opacity: .8;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  filter: alpha(opacity=50);
  opacity: 1;
  text-decoration: none;
}

button.close {
  background: transparent;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.close').on("click", function() {
        $(this).parents('div').fadeOut();
      });
    });
  </script>

  <div class="banner well notice bg-green">
    Close this banner <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Try moving you script to the end of your body*:

```css
.banner {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100px;
  opacity: 0.6;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding-top: 5px;
}

.close {
  color: #fff;
  filter: alpha(opacity=20);
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1;
  opacity: .8;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  filter: alpha(opacity=50);
  opacity: 1;
  text-decoration: none;
}

button.close {
  background: transparent;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <div class="banner well notice bg-green">


    Close this banner <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
  </div>
  <script>
    $('.close').on("click", function() {
      $('.banner').fadeOut();
    });
  </script>
</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should bind the click event only inside $(document). ready ();

Please refer: [Why should $.click() be enclosed within $(document).ready()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10092762/why-should-click-be-enclosed-within-document-ready)

**Why it works when placed separately?**

When you put it in a HTML code document.ready doesn't get any listener.But when you put it in separate section in Jsfiddle it automatically puts it inside document.ready and your code works. To confirm this you can check the source of your output iframe.